# Best method of back end pseudo user validation with DynammoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple app that is using a dynammoDB table with node/express as the back end. I let users add and then edit things. I am trying to determine the best way to verify that a user owns the item that they are editing/deleting.

Here is what i've looked at. Is there a better method?

```
1. User cognito ID is part of the item when created
2. User token is sent as part of edit
3. Item is pulled from table when edit starts
4. Token is decoded and the id is compared to the one pulled from the table
```

The obvious problem here is that every edit requires a read. This seems wrong.

Another method

```
1. User cognito ID is part of the item when created
2. User token is sent as part of edit
3. Original id is sent from the item as well
4. Token is decoded and the decoded id is compared to the one sent
```

This doesn't require a read, but would let a clever person edit things that they shouldn't.

Is there another way that I am missing? I don't want to create some separate IAM policy for each user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use DynamoDBs fine grained access control that can dynamically allow Cognito users only read/edit their own data:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/fine-grained-access-control-for-amazon-dynamodb/

Comment: I have seen this, but I thought that it was just adding an IAM policy for each user?

Comment: No, one policy and the `${www.amazon.com:user_id}` resolves that users Cognito id

Comment: OK. Thanks. I guess that I misread this initially.

Comment: This is still really confusing to me and I have a ton of questions. Why is it asking for an identity provider of Facebook, Google, or Login with Amazon? I just want to apply this to cognito users, not necessarily federated users. Does "Login with Amazon" mean cognito? If I want to ensure that users can only edit items that they created, how do I do that without setting a policy that affects everything else?

Comment: I'm also confused as to how AWS knows the users cognito ID when I authenticate on a react app that doesn't talk to my back end, but the AWS fine grained access on dynammoDB takes place after a write from a node app through a lambda?